# Angular 2, use variable in @Component styles

Tags: angular

I have a plunker here - https://plnkr.co/edit/fzNJ7FLYxWbLPoxtYpEw?p=preview

Its a simple angular app.

I'm capturing the height of a div using @ViewChild and nativeElement.offsetHeight

Is it possible to uss this number in the styles block of the component.

In my example I have attempted it but commmented it out.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './src/app.html',
  styles: [`
    .blockTwo {
      background: yellow;
      //height: this.contentHeight+px;
      height: 200px;
    }
  `]
})
```

=

```
import {Component, ElementRef, ViewChild, AfterViewInit} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './src/app.html',
  styles: [`
    .blockTwo {
      background: yellow;
      //height: this.contentHeight+px;
      height: 200px;
    }
  `]
})

export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit{

  @ViewChild('content') 
  elementView: ElementRef;

  contentHeight: number;

  constructor() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
      this.contentHeight = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
  }

}
```

Comment: You can use this style binding syntax: `[style.height.px]="contentHeight"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is doable using ngStyle

In your app.html change the yellow div to this:

```
<div class="blockTwo" [ngStyle]="style">
</div>
```

and in your app.ts

```
style: any;
ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.contentHeight = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
  this.style = {"height": this.contentHeight+"px"}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can just do like this

```
//this line is exaple , but point is make use of ngStyle
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'max-height.px': height}">...</some-element>
```

and define and initialize `height` in your ts file , that will do work for you

or kind of this help

```
<div #parentdiv style="background-color:blue;height:1000px">
  <div [ngStyle]="{'max-height.px': parentdiv.offsetHeight}">
    hallo
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

User [ngStyle] Directive.

```
<div class="content" #content [ngStyle]="{'height':'contentHeight'}">

</div>

<div>
  <h2>{{contentHeight}}</h2>

  <div class="blockTwo">

  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me - I need the '.blockTwo' to use the height - https://plnkr.co/edit/fzNJ7FLYxWbLPoxtYpEw?p=preview

Comment: In your plnkr style is not defined. Use this code below elementView to define.
`elementView: ElementRef;
  
  style:{"height": string};`